# Suggestions on inexpensive WiFi equipment that can route specified SSID to specified port?

Tags: wifi

I want to have one WiFi device that can route traffic from one SSID to a specified port and another SSID to another port. Also this device needs to support 802.11g/n at minimum. Prefer it to cost under $200.

The idea is to physically separate office traffic from guest traffic, but without maintaining multiple devices.